# Any way to force TestNG to use unique threads (do not reuse) when running in parallel?

Tags: multithreading, selenium, testng, threadpool

I am using thread id as a key to a map that keeps track of all parameters that are loaded from the XML, but I need it to reload the parameters with every new  section because some test sections overwrite some parameters. When TestNG creates all threads it seems to reuse them, so when I get instance of the configuration in the map, it finds the wrong one. Any way to force the thread ids to be unique?

**Update:**
Here is what is going on with configuration: thread-count="3", parallel="tests"

With 4 test sections - The first 3 run in parallel right away with unique threads, but the fourth one waits for one of the first three to finish and then grabs one of the threads, so its thread ID is not unique.

Comment: Are you running these tests as sequential or parallel?

Comment: Tests are run in parallel (all tests within <test> section are run sequentially, but different <test> sections are run in parallel). I need each <test> section in XML to have a unique thread.

Comment: And you can't change the thread-count to 4?

Comment: I can, but it is not a good solution. 3 and 4 was just an example, in our actual suite it is 12 threads and 20 <test> sections. At some point it will be too many threads and either the test server wouldn't be able to handle it or the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. In my @beforeMethod I set the name of the current thread to be the name of  and for the key in my map I use thread's name followed by threads id.